# Can you have a loader without fragments

Tags: android-fragments, loader

Very basic loader question.

My WIMMOne watch uses Android 2.1 (version 7).

There are no orientation changes, etc. with a watch.  The small screen does not have room for any layout changes.  So no need to deal with any kind of layout change.

The app I am working on now simply reads from a cursor, and displays an open ended scrolling list.  My first app had a fragment and that was a pain.  So I decided since I don't need fragments I will do away with the complexities of fragments.

I START WITH:

```
public class PhoneListActivity extends Activity
         implements     LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks <Cursor>;
```

THEN:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.phone_list_activity);
```

FINALLY:

```
   getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

BUT:

Because it is 2.1 I need to use:

```
getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
```

BUT: -
That generates compile errors, so I need to use:

```
public class PhoneListActivity extends FragmentActivity . . .  (not just Activity)
```

BUT: - 
It immediately crashes on load in the ContentProvider.

Postings in various sites refer to "Activities and ActivityFragments".

SO: QUESTION 1: Can my main class use "extends FragmentActivity"  without setting up a separate fragment  (ie: leave it just as an Activity).

QUESTION 2:  If not, does that mean that to use a loader I must set up a separate fragment and deal with the issues of fragments?

Many thanks,
Clark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The answer is ***YES***.

I redid part of the program and it now works *without* using fragments.  It has the open ended scrolling being loaded from a cursor and basically the same structure above

I think something in handling my cursor was causing it to crash.

Clark